# Django Admin page not displaying

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

A couple days ago I was able to get to the django admin login page but today when I try to hit 127.0.0.1:8000/admin I get redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ which brings up the DRF view for JSON testing

Am I missing something? I am not sure what would have changed. I looked at the last few days of version control and dont see where anything changed.

Comment: **when I try to hit 127.0.0.1:8000/admin I get redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/** : Your session has expired, so you have been logged out. that's why you have been redirected to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/` to log in again...

Comment: which makes perfect sense. But why didnt it just bring me to the basic login screen instead of the django rest framework login post?

Comment: did you override the `login admin` view?, how can it keep the same URL and display another view/template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it happened to me when I unintentionally included `rest_framework.urls` and `admin.site.urls` in the same url. Such as:

```
url(r'^admin/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

So, make sure these are included in defferent urls such as:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar issue. For mw, what happened was I had my route for the API registered at the root like this:

```
path('', include('app.urls'))
```

which made the admin page render in the DRF view. Moving the app to a directory path at:

```
path('app', include('app.urls'))
```

fixes it.